# Get Selected value in <a> angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get the selected value from a dropdown menu. I always get the error of missing `ng-model`.

I tried to pass the selected value in the `ng-click` but it didn't work.

Here's my dropdown menu

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a  href=""   ng-click="dropboxitemselected(xx)" >Cible</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="marque()">Marque</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-model="modele()">Modéle</a></li>
      <li><a href=""  ng-model="calculateur()">Calculateur</a></li>             
</ul>
```

And here my controller

```
$scope.dropboxitemselected = function (x) {
    alert(x);
```

}

I need the selected value as I am going to insert the value into an API then resend the data selected.

Comment: i think it should be binded in *li tag*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its enough to change xx to 'cible' like this :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a  href=""   ng-click="dropboxitemselected('cible')" >Cible</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="marque()">Marque</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-model="modele()">Modéle</a></li>
  <li><a href=""  ng-model="calculateur()">Calculateur</a></li>             
</ul>
```

And you'll see an alert saying 'cible' on your page when clicked first link.

Dis moi si ça marché pour toi.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know which of the items is selected you need to add `ng-click="dropboxitemselected('POINT_NAME_HERE')"` to each of them:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="" ng-click="dropboxitemselected('cible')">Cible</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="dropboxitemselected('Marque')">Marque</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="dropboxitemselected('Modéle')">Modéle</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="dropboxitemselected('Calculateur')">Calculateur</a></li>             
</ul>
```

Aside from that, [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), is something different from click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just add quotes if you are willing to send a static value, else send a scope varibale.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" >
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a  href=""   ng-click="dropboxitemselected('xx')" >Cible</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="marque()">Marque</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-model="modele()">Modéle</a></li>
      <li><a href=""  ng-model="calculateur()">Calculateur</a></li>             
</ul>
<div>
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t6ncvg5w/